# How to RBAC and Authentication with Spring Security 6?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to authenticate my Spring Boot app with HttpBasic but it fails everytime I enter the crendentials to login form.

User.java:

```
    @Entity
    public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @Email
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<UserRole> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<UserRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

JpaUserDetailsService.java:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userRepository
            .findByUsername(username)
            .map(User::new)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + username));
}
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {


@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {

                    auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/users/register").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll();
                        auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                    }
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .build();

}
    @Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Errors:

[As you can see bad credentials in the login website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu0UR.png)

And in the terminal:

```
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@625430f8
o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /all
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
    o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/all?continue to session
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using And [Not [RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]], MediaTypeRequestMatcher [contentNegotiationStrategy=org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager@7a8e35d1, matchingMediaTypes=[application/xhtml+xml, image/*, text/html, text/plain], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint@625430f8
o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login
o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Empty encoded password
    o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value
o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /login?error
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login?error
```

I tried to beatufiy some of it by hand hence the indentation errors.

Please keep in mind, I am also trying to tie my roles to my `@PreAuthorize(hasRole("{ROLE}"))` which I defined in my `UserController.java`:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER')")
@GetMapping("/users")
public User getUserById(@RequestParam("id") Long userId) {
    return jpaUserDetailsService.getUserById(userId);
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@GetMapping("/all")
public List<User> listAllUsers() {
    return jpaUserDetailsService.getAllUsers();
}
```

As you can see from my `User` class they are tied with a `@ManyToMany` `user_id` -> `role_id` relation

Edit: Decided to provide some more information about database here:

```
SELECT * FROM user;
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | username     | password                                                     | email                 |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 | john_doe     | $2a$10$3ClKqruSzzf0L26VNDgPWe2jhYSnNjnQgAUnSuDFvaVxlmrAbaDN2 | john.doe@example.com  |
|  2 | this_is_hard | $2a$10$VRAa8lNNQVmkWeaCqd3pL.SqDGNtr6g/rBg48WpScCm149FDAbtG2 | this.hard@example.com |
|  7 | hope_works   | $2a$10$wneewBVPDLe0tGIvYXrhtOaEQ6qMsU2DJ4uDhQFWcoWgQVnO2p7yi | this.hard@example.com |
|  9 | no_dupes     | $2a$10$h7pFQR0gpfSCvW3ZlWy76e8fQI6jb7J3zcd6KNSwxu/2fouBqGbI6 | no.dupes@example.com  |
| 11 | admin        | $2a$10$63ILA6oYAoV35nzJRryGKeiiTPYnrrsQTe1FFwqdTCgOJGMvj7Afm | admin@example.com     |
+----+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
SELECT * FROM user_role;
+----+---------------+
| id | name          |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | ROLE_CUSTOMER |
|  2 | ROLE_ADMIN    |
+----+---------------+
SELECT * FROM user_roles;
+---------+---------+
| user_id | role_id |
+---------+---------+
|       7 |       1 |
|       9 |       1 |
|      11 |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: and what is in your password field in your database

Comment: @Toerktumlare In my database there is a encrypted version of the password I registered, using `/users/register` which i use with a json request body, nothing too crazy. 

Debug logs show lots of stuff about `DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint`  successfully matching stuff and redirecting and honestly lots of stuff that looks like that will require deep expertise of Spring Security and my goal isn't achieving that at all. I just want the functionality.

I will try to add some more of debug logs so maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Just added some more debug logs, if you are still interested.

Comment: could you please enable `DEBUG` logs and update your question with them

Comment: @Toerktumlare I found the problem and solved it after some debugging. Btw, the logs you see in the edited question ARE from `DEBUG` logs except a few `WARN` logs. The problem was solved by using a proper constructor in User class. But I am still trying for PreAuthorize access. I guess, I am doing something wrong there and just the `@PreAuthorize` keywords aren't enough.